# How to install nodejs in a vps hosting centos 6.5

Tags: node.js, centos, putty, vps

I currently build a website with nodejs using expressjs framework. Now I want to upload it to a live server. My share hosting company say no. So I bought a VPS hosting, but I dont know what to do next. This is my first time using vps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't install a service directly by client, because there is no concrete way to do that. A reason for security, you even have no permission to install plugin by terminal.
To sum up, I suggest you ask the VPS supplier who you pay for to serve nodejs hosting.

BTW, you can check that is there a enviroment for nodejs on your VPS first.